# RuntimeTypeHandle.Allocate() is not defined

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm attempting to write a slightly tweaked `Array.Sort()` method implementation based in large part off of the standard CLR implementation. The full source can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/arraysorthelper.cs), but the only issue I have is with the following method used to instantiate the `ArraySortHelper` object.

```
private static ICustomArraySortHelper<TKey, TValue> CreateArraySortHelper()
{
    if (typeof(IComparable<TKey>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TKey)))
    {
        defaultArraySortHelper = (ICustomArraySortHelper<TKey, TValue>)RuntimeTypeHandle.Allocate(typeof(GenericCustomArraySortHelper<string, string>).TypeHandle.Instantiate(new Type[] { typeof(TKey), typeof(TValue) }));
    }
    else
    {
        defaultArraySortHelper = new CustomArraySortHelper<TKey, TValue>();
    }
    return defaultArraySortHelper;
}
```

When I try to compile, both the `RuntimeTypeHandle.Allocate()` and `TypeHandle.Instantiate()` calls come back as not being defined.

> 'System.RuntimeTypeHandle' does not contain a definition for
>   'Allocate'
>   'System.RuntimeTypeHandle' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Instantiate' and no extension method 'Instantiate' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.RuntimeTypeHandle' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The MSDN documentation also appears to be lacking these methods. Why can't I access these? Am I missing some reference? Lastly, if I did not want to add an external reference, what is the best line of code to replace the offending line while maintaining the same objective? It's not clear to me why reflection is required for this construction. Can I get by with a `new` call similar to the `else` branch of the code?

**SOLUTION:**

Following the suggestion by **pinkfloydx33**, I found this code works fine as a replacement:

```
Type genericType = typeof(GenericCustomArraySortHelper<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TKey), typeof(TValue));
defaultArraySortHelper = (ICustomArraySortHelper<TKey, TValue>)Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

The reason this simpler line of code does ***not*** work

```
defaultArraySortHelper = (ICustomArraySortHelper<TKey, TValue>)new GenericCustomArraySortHelper<TKey, TValue>();
```

is due to the error

> The type 'TKey' cannot be used as type parameter 'TKey' in the generic
>   type or method 'GenericCustomArraySortHelper<TKey,TValue>'. There is
>   no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TKey' to
>   'System.IComparable<TKey>'.

This is the whole point of the if-statement, which is abundantly obvious in retrospect.

Comment: `Allocate` is an `internal` method. I imagine some of those types are internal also. It's also marked `extern` and is an `InternalCall` method which means there is some compiler/jitter trickery involved with it. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtimehandles.cs,37f06fadf702c22c,references

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks for that insight; makes sense. Any thoughts on replacing that line with a more standard `new` call? Why do they appear to be creating a `GenericCustomArraySortHelper<string, string>` object with reflection and then overwriting the `string` types with the actual generic types?

Comment: Can you not just use `Activator.CreateInstance`? And I can't answer that question. Those types are all implementation details sort of...and I don't know how they work. Really you'd create the generic type yourself `typeof(whatever<,>).MakeGenericType(new[]{typeof(X),typeof(y)})`. Perhaps they way they do it is a "work around" to `typeof(whatever<a, b>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(....)`